# html2pdf not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, html2pdf

I am using Codeigniter HMVC structure.When i will put limit in my query with 375 than its working properly but if i will remove that limit than html2pdf is giving me blank pdf

I tried to debug for that but i can't get what is going on ?
I just came to know parsingHTML.class.php have function with name setHTML which is giving me blank

Code :

```
 public function setHTML($html)
    {
        // remove the HTML in comment
        print_r($html);exit;
        $html = preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/isU', '', $html);
        print_r($html);exit;
        // save the HTML code
        $this->_html = $html;
    }
```

IF i will echo before preg_replace than i can see html page and after preg_replace its giving me blank html.

My html page is very large so may be that cause the issue ?
if yes than anyone please provide me debug points or something to check the issue?

Any suggestions to check any other places or debug points ?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: " after preg_replace its giving me blank html." then thats the issue NOT  html2pdf

Comment: Dagon@ I am expect same but if i will put limit in my query than its working so what is issue that i can't get ?

Comment: How can i debug in html2pdf ?